# Prestashop Modules Specifc Page error

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I have a module and I want to display it on a specific page. For example this module is configured to display only on the homepage. I want to display it on a specific CMS plage.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a module on a page only if you can add it to a specific HOOK.
That means that

a) if there isn't a hook on a given page you won't be able to show it.

b) if the developer that wrote that module didn't create the code for a specific hook  you need to add it manually either it will return an error when you try to add it (aka, a function called hookPrestashopHookName)

Unluckily the CMS page doesn't have a specific hook available, just the left/right column that are available on all the pages. 
To add a custom hook, and then bind it to your module you should follow this procedure:
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/173027-solved-how-to-create-a-new-hook-in-15-am-i-doing-it-wrong/page-2

Then if you had the module already installed you can either reinstall it or transplant the module to your new hook by going to your admin and Modules --> Positions --> +Transplant a module -->Select the module you want to add and then "Hook Into" your created hook.